# How to prevent a double-tap on a ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gesture

Is there anyway to prevent double tap on `ListView` in Android? I found this when i accidentally tapped item on `ListView` and it opened up two new window. is there any way to prevent it from opening a same window twice.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code or an image? Usually things are processed quickly which would prevent that behavior.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534369/avoid-button-multiple-rapid-clicks/16534470#16534470

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Preventing Double Click On A Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608720/android-preventing-double-click-on-a-button)

Answer (score 2):

Just add `listView.setEnabled(false);` on select of listview and after select when response will come or back button press just write---- `listView.setEnabled(true);`

Comment: A possible solution but not the best practice :(

Comment: In my case It works. When back to the listview I overrided OnResume() method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636039/how-to-catch-event-of-coming-back-to-an-activity-after-hitting-back

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with introducing and Override of isEnabled method

```
    @Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false;
}
```

for the listview.

introduce a boolean for flag and an int to maintain last clicked position

```
 int recentlyClickedPoisition;
        boolean flagRecentClickedPoisition;
```

override the isEnabled method as follows

```
   @Override
   public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        if (flagRecentClickedPoisition && recentlyClickedPoisition == position) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

than set the last clicked position from your click listener as follows

```
public void setLastClickedPoisition(int recentlyClickedPoisition) {
    flagRecentClickedPoisition = true;
    this.recentlyClickedPoisition = recentlyClickedPoisition;
}
```

Hope this will work for you to prevent from double tap, enhance accordinly.

Answer (score 0):

You should **restrict the target activity (one that opens when an item is clicked) to have only one instance at any point of time.**

Answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995987/is-there-any-way-to-have-one-and-only-one-instance-of-each-activity) should help you in achieving that. That way if you accidentally double click, you will still see just one new screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using just single item like TextView in list then just create a class implements **OnItemClickListener** in this call and then in to **onItemClick**() method initialize myListView.**setOnItemClickListenet**(null);
then use **Handler.postDelayed** method to again set **onItemClickListener**.
like

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new MyClickListenerClass());
```

This is working for all time in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In your XAML view page place isEnable property as a bindable and two way mode.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding items}"
                                  x:Name="listview"
                                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                                  IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnable, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  RowHeight="10"
                                  SelectionMode="Single"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
```

In viewmodel of your xaml page :

```
    private bool _isEnable = true;
    public bool IsEnable
    {
        get => _isEnable;
        set
        {
            _isEnable = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsEnable));
        }
    }


public ICommand TapCommand => new Command<//Model>(async (obj) =>
    {
        IsEnable = false;
       //your stuff 
        IsEnable = true;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a two pane layout, a listview that controls a detail view. First I thought a **delayed handler** is the worst idea, but after testing it is the simplest. Otherwise I would have to communicate between activity and fragment to enable the listview item once another detail was loaded. Error prone and complex.

```
/*example with Handler():*/

        final boolean[] allowClick = {true};

        myview.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            //exit if not allowed
            if(!allowClick[0])
                return;

            //do stuff

            //we clicked, block another click
            allowClick[0] =false;

            //wait 0.7 seconds and allow another click
            new Handler().postDelayed(() -> allowClick[0] =true, 700);

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is implemented on a ListFragment. If the tap dismissed the ListFragment to show a detail view (which it normally would), the next time the ListFragment appears, the tap counter is reset in OnResume():

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

    int mTapCounter;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //Set-Reset ListView clickListener
        mTapCounter = 0;
    }

    //ListView item tap event handler
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(@NonNull ListView l, @NonNull View v, int position, long id) {

        //Disable click listener to prevent double-tap
        mTapCounter++;

        //Only process single-tap
        if(mTapCounter == 1) {

            /* YOUR TAP HANDLER CODE HERE */
        }

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }
}
```